# Sync database content with django

Tags: django, synchronization

We have a local sqlite3 and an online mariaDB database and want to sync the content within django 1.10.3.

The settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'online_database',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'HOST': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    },
    'local':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'local_database'
    }
}
```

With `python manage.py migrate --database=local` we were able to sync all the model structures but additionally we are interested in syncing the content of the tables. Is there anything implemented in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do it using [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/). Use the following:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --database online_database <other parameters> > fixture.json
python manage.py loaddata --database local_database <other parameters> path/to/your/fixtures/fixture.json
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot, it works with fixtures but I had to use `python manage.py dumpdata --database online_database <other parameters> > fixture.json` and `python manage.py loaddata --database local_database <other parameters> path/to/your/fixtures/fixture.json`

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer to match the working solution.